# JAVASCRIPT: method assigned to another method of same object - changing value of first changes second one

Tags: javascript, object, methods, variable-assignment, slice

So i have an javascript object called `game`which has two methods:

```
function game() {
    this.TxtRevealed = new Array();
    this.TxtRevealedBackup = new Array();
[...]
}
```

Now, outside an object i assign one two another:

```
game.TxtRevealedBackup = game.TxtRevealed;
```

After a while i change `game.TxtRevealed`(i use `slice` function to cut some values from it). 
And now happens something i do not intend: automatically `game.TxtRevealedBackup` changes also to new value of `game.TxtRevealed`.

I'd expect that `game.TxtRevealedBackup` would be same as `game.TxtRevealed` was in moment of assigning. It works as if `game.TxtRevealedBackup` was pointing to value that is represented by `game.TxtRevealed` continously, not the value it was in moment of assignment.

Why is it happening and how to make it working i'd expect?

Kalreg.

Comment: Yes, objects work like this. BTW, `slice` does not alter the array; most probably you mean `splice`.

Comment: Most object oriented programming languages work this way. Objects are represented as references. *"how to make it working i'd expect"* You can can clone the object.

Comment: what should i do to achieve my goal?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+array+clone

Comment: @Oriol: Good find.

Answer (score 0):

Objects do work by reference. If you want to clone objects see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/5950307).

Comment: i'd expect that there is much more simple solution than that, something like adding & to name of variable or sth.

Comment: Nope. But if you are using jQuery you could use something like `var cloned = $.extend({}, original);`.